# Create and append an iframe to all existing target divs and populate the src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I want to create and append an iframe to the `.thumbnail.excerpt` divs below - and then populate the `src` attribute with the link from the `a` element. I have managed to do this with jQuery, but looking for a vanilla JS solution.

Vanilla JS isnt my strong suit but so far I managed to append an iframe to the first element in the DOM - how do I append the iframe to all target elements in the DOM?

```js
var el = document.querySelector('.thumbnail-excerpt');
el.innerHTML += '<iframe itemprop="video" class="video-embed" src=”video” width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
```

```html
<div class="thumbnail-excerpt">
  <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.example.com"></a>
</div>

<div class="thumbnail-excerpt">
  <a class="colorbox cboxElement" href="http://www.example.com"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what meet your needs.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var thumbnails = document.getElementsByClassName('thumbnail-excerpt');
    var thumbnail, videoLink, finalContent;
    var insertPattern = '<iframe itemprop="video" class="video-embed" src="[video-link]" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>';
    for (var i = 0; i < thumbnails.length; i++) {
        thumbnail = thumbnails[i];
        videoLink = thumbnail.children[0].href;
        finalContent = insertPattern.replace('[video-link]', videoLink);
        if (typeof thumbnail.innerHTML == 'undefined') {
            thumbnail.innerHTML = finalContent;
        } else {
            thumbnail.innerHTML += finalContent;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Html without changes.